# Any magic command to extract an array from array of custom objects?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a class like this

```
class ValueTimestamp {
  let value: Double
  let timestamp : Double
  init(value:Double, timestamp:Double) {
    self.value = valuer
    self.timestamp = timestamp
  }
}
```

Then I have an array filled with `ValueTimestamp` objects. Let's call this, `myArray`.

Now I want to manipulate the array, to extract, for example the elements with values bigger than 10.

Because I am new to swift, I would do this:

```
// this will create an array with Doubles
let sub = myArray.map($0.value > 10)

var newArray : [ValueTimestamp] = []
for i in 0..< myArray.count {
  let newValue = ValueTimestamp.init(value:sub[i], timestamp:myArray[i])
  newArray.append(newValue)
}
```

and now I have `newArray` that contains the elements from `myArray` with values bigger than 10.

Is there any magic command using `.map`, `.flatmap` or whatever that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you looking for is `filter` method:

```swift
public func filter(_ isIncluded: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Element]
```

It takes as parameter closure, which take 1 element and return `true` if element should be added in resulting array or `false` if it should be filtered out.

Your code:

```swift
let biggerThem10 = myArray.filter { $0.value > 10 }
```